# PCA analysis incites memory allocation problem. How to solve this without reducing image resolution or number of images

Tags: python, image, pca, feature-extraction

using PCA (principle component analysis) to extract features from a set of 4K images giving me the memory error

*File "/home/paul90/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/_pca.py", line 369, in fit_transform
    U, S, V = self._fit(X)*

***MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (23339520, 40) and data type float32***

I am trying to extract 30 features (# of components) from 4K images and getting this error.

- ***Pseudocode:***

***immatrix = np.array([np.array(Image.open(im, 'r')).flatten() for im in file_list], 'f')***

***x = StandardScaler().fit_transform(immatrix)***

***pc_train = pca.fit_transform(x)***

Filelist is list of images (currently I have 600 images)

I can't reduce the number of images in the list and can't reduce the initial 4K resolution. In this context,how can I solve this memory allocation issue?

It will be a great help if anyone can tell me the steps to avoid the memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

As this problem stated, you have to reconfigure your system to make more RAM available to the run-time system.

However, I suspect that you can finesse the problem by iterating through the images, rather than loading all of them into one large NumPy array.  Rather than using the monolithic processing tools, you'll need to write code to perform the same computations serially.

Answer (score 0):

It is common for larger datasets to not be able to fit into memory so an operation like PCA cannot be performed in its *pure* theoretical way.  There is another PCA function that sklearn has called *Incremental PCA* which can be thought of like a model that takes batches. Since you don't have your full code viewable, I will just copy a portion of the [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_incremental_pca.html) which does both PCA and Incremental PCA so you get the idea.  The documentation for the method is [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.IncrementalPCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.IncrementalPCA).

```
# Authors: Kyle Kastner
# License: BSD 3 clause

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA, IncrementalPCA

iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

n_components = 2
ipca = IncrementalPCA(n_components=n_components, batch_size=10)
X_ipca = ipca.fit_transform(X)

pca = PCA(n_components=n_components)
X_pca = pca.fit_transform(X)
```